# Javascript not outputting the image

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to embed this so that it gets URL parameters then it inserts them into the image tag then outputs said image tag

```js
<script>
    function myFunction() {
    var baseUrl = 'https://domain.idevaffiliate.com/lead.php';
var u = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

// u.search: ?p1=welcome&p2=hello
var newUrl = baseUrl  + u.search;
console.log(newUrl);

// or 
newUrl = baseUrl + '?profile=1&lead_id=' + u.searchParams.get("email") + '&lead_value={lead_value}&customer_name=' + u.searchParams.get("name")+ '&customer_email=' + u.searchParams.get("email") + '&opt1=' + u.searchParams.get("phone_number")
console.log(newUrl);

//to display the image

document.body.innerHTML += '<img src="' + newUrl +'" style="height:0px; width:0px; border:0px;">';
    }
    </script>
```

Thus, the end result would be an output like this:

```html
<img src="https://domain.idevaffiliate.com/lead.php?profile=1&lead_id=someone%40gmail.com&lead_value={lead_value}&customer_name=Tom+Jones&customer_email=someone%40gmail.com&opt1=2314567890" style="height:0px; width:0px; border:0px;" />
```

Comment: What results are you getting? What is the error or problem?

Comment: It's not outputting the image. https://jsfiddle.net/x0vd1bh3/1/?email=someone%40gmail.com&name=Tom+Jones&phone_number=2314567890

Comment: To start with, you're not calling the function so the code doesn't even run

Comment: Yeah, javascript isn't my strong suit, been piecing together what I find in articles. What's the fix?

Comment: Well, calling the function: `myFunction();` That way you'll at least see the error messages that the code throws.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sx6cz1h3/?email=someone%40gmail.com&name=Tom+Jones&phone_number=2314567890

I removed the function part. Got this error:
"https://domain.idevaffiliate.com/lead.phpundefined"
<a class='gotoLine' href='#33:59'>33:59</a> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

All set:

```js
<script>
    var baseUrl = 'https://domain.idevaffiliate.com/lead.php';
    var u = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

    newUrl = baseUrl + '?profile=1&lead_id=' + u.get("email") + '&lead_value={lead_value}&customer_name=' + u.get("name")+ '&customer_email=' + u.get("email") + '&opt1=' + u.get("phone_number")
    console.log(newUrl);

    //to display the image
 document.body.innerHTML += '<img src="' + encodeURI(newUrl) +'" style="height:0px; width:0px; border:0px;">';
</script>
```